# imei check said server down

Tags: itunes

on a imei check it said server down, please could someone tell me what it means, as I bought a sencond hand iphone 3gs and cannot get it set up, plus I need it unlocked as its on at&t network to work in the uk, all help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: As for your ultimate goal, are you aiming to purchase an official unlock or to jailbreak and unlock it? If it is the latter, would you mind posting the first 6 characters of the device serial number so that I can confirm whether that's possible on your exact device?

Comment: Hi, the 88043x1redg, the phone is on an american network called at&t so was wondering how I could make it work in the uk, thank uou very uch for replying,

Answer (score 1):

Activation failed when a communication with Apple servers was expected.

(Official unlocks rely on having Apple send your device a list of approved SIMs during activation, and thus having the unlocker request Apple to approve your device for all cards).

This sounds like an occasional, temporary error: if it persists, I would be inclined check the hosts file on your computer to make sure it isn't redirecting any Apple servers, although I haven't ever heard of a modification that would break activation in this way.

---

The "043" in your serial number stands for "made in year (201)0, week 43": you can use the jailbreak tool redsn0w to install and then remove the iPad baseband, enabling you to software-unlock your iPhone as described in this guide: http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-downgrade-iphone-3gs-3g-06.15.00-to-05.13.04-baseband-for-unlock-and-working-gps/

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help, I can jailbreak it even though I can't get past connect to itunes, x

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the Apple Activation servers are under serious DDoS attack